# Combining two enums in a collection to fetch one of the values

Tags: c#, enums

I have two enums

```js
public enum YogabandEventDuration
{
    [Display(Name = "30 min")]
    ThirtyMinutes = 30,
    [Display(Name = "45 min")]
    FortyFiveMinutes = 45,
    [Display(Name = "60 min")]
    SixtyMinutes = 60,
    [Display(Name = "75 min")]
    SeventyFiveMinutes = 75,
    [Display(Name = "90 min")]
    NinetyMinutes = 90
}

public enum PrivatePrice
{
    [Display(Name = "$8.95")]
    ThirtyMinute = 895,
    [Display(Name = "$14.95")]
    FortyFiveMinute = 1495,
    [Display(Name = "$19.95")]
    SixtyMinute = 1495,
    [Display(Name = "$24.95")]
    SeventyFiveMinute = 2495,
    [Display(Name = "$27.95")]
    NinetyMinute = 2795
}
```

Is there a way to match up the values in each enum 1-to-1 so that I can do a search like this

```
var theClassPrice = GetPrice(YogabandEventDuration);
```

and passing in ThirtyMinutes would return 895

Comment: I don't think enums are neccessarily the right approach for what you are trying to achieve. You might want a database table or a configuration file or just a dictionary.

Comment: It's a really weird thing you want but : you can parse a string to get it's enum value

Comment: I'm just looking for a simpler solution to what I have now, which is a case statement that looks for a length and then returns a price, but I'm implementing this in different areas and would like to consolidate it into one class somewhere

Comment: Well `ThrityMinutes` in yoga duration has a S and `ThirtyMinute` in price don't..

Comment: just a typo from getting it into the thread

Comment: So a parse will work `var time = YogabandEventDuration.ThrityMinutes;
var price = Enum.Parse(typeof(PrivatePrice), time.ToString() );`.

Comment: price returns an object, do I need to cast it to something after?

Comment: `var intValue = (int)price;`.. to get the int value of your enum. Im surprice you know how to access Display name metadata but not the value of the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would have gone with something like this,  as per @SteveJ suggestion

```
var privateSession = new Dictionary<Session, double>()
{
   { Session.ThirtyMinute, 8.95},
   { Session.FortyFiveMinute, 14.95 },
   { Session.SixtyMinute, 19.95  },
   { Session.SeventyFiveMinute, 24.95 },
   { Session.NinetyMinute, 27.95 }
};
```

And then use an enum for session times

```
public enum Session
{
    ThirtyMinute,
    FortyFiveMinute,
    SixtyMinute,
    SeventyFiveMinute,
    NinetyMinute
}
```

Comment: I think what I want is something like { YogabandEventDuration.ThrityMinutes, PrivatePrice.ThirtyMinutes} in the dictionary that way I can alter the price in just the enum

Comment: What is the gain of just editing the enum, instead of just editing the database or the Json? Editing enum means recompile no live edit. Enum is not the good way to store those information. Store those in array/ class so any class could just acess those like they would with an enum; And set the acess to where it store in this class if it's not a static array that will never change. this way every one use the class the class say it's in database/Json/handwrited in code. And you win on every level with not a huge modification.

Comment: I'm storing them in enums because they are being displayed in dropdown lists in the html views. So the students will pick a duration then get a price

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is really Strange:
You can [parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) a string to get it's enum equivalent value.

```
var time = YogabandEventDuration.ThrityMinutes.ToString();
var price = Enum.Parse(typeof(PrivatePrice), time );
var intValue = (int)price;
```

giving you a simple function as you ask :

```
private int GetPrice(YogabandEventDuration duration) {
    return (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(PrivatePrice), duration.ToString());
}
```